# $a_n$-Consistency of the Largest Order Statistic (Jun Shao Example 2.34)

Tags: limits, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, asymptotics

I am learning about different modes of consistency in statistics. I am having a hard time understanding the concept of $a_n$-*consistency*.

Here's the definition: Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of positive constants diverging to $\infty$. $T_n(X)$ is called $a_n$-*consistent* for $\vartheta$ iff $a_n[T_n(X) - \vartheta] = O_p(1)$ w.r.t. any $P \in \mathcal{P}$, where $X = (X_1, \cdots, X_n)$ is a sample from a population $P \in \mathcal{P}$, $\vartheta$ is the parameter vector associated with the population $P$, and $T_n(X)$ is a point estimator of $\vartheta$ for every $n$.

In a follow-up example, he showed that the largest order statistics $X_{(n)}$ is $n^{(m+1)^{-1}}$-consistent when $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ are i.i.d. with a continuous c.d.f. $F$ satisfying $F(\theta) = 1$ for some $\theta \in \mathcal{R}$, $F(x) < 1$ for any $x < \theta$, the $i$-th order left hand derivative of $F$ at $\theta$ exists and vanishes for any $i \leq m$, and the $m$-th order left hand derivative of $F$ exists and is non-zero. $m$ is a nonnegative integer.

I have two questions about this example:

1. Shao quoted a "fact" that $P(n[1-F(X_{(n)})] \geq s) = (1 - s/n)^n$. However, it doesn't seem very intuitive to me how I can get to this "fact". How do I derive this?
2. The second question is, how do I use the "fact" given in 1., and the Taylor expansion of
   $$1 - F(X_{(n)}) = \frac{(-1)^mF^{(m+1)}(\theta-)}{(m+1)!}(\theta - X_{(n)})^{m+1} + o(|\theta - X_{(n)}|^{m+1}) \; a.s.,$$
   to get to the conclusion that $(\theta - X_{(n)})^{m+1} = O_p(n^{-1})$?

The definition $O_p$ is: $X_n = O_p(Y_n)$ iff, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a constant $C_{\epsilon} > 0$ such that $\sup_n P(\|X_n\| \geq C_{\epsilon}|Y_n|) < \epsilon$, where $X_n$ is a random vector and $Y_n$ is a random variable.

Thank you very much.

Here is the screenshot of the example:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Note that
   \begin{align*}
   P(n[1 - F(X_n)] \ge s) = P\left(F(X_n) \le 1 - \frac{s}{n}\right) = F_{X_{(n)}}\left(F^{-1}\left(1 - \frac{s}{n}\right)\right) = \left(1 - \frac{s}{n}\right)^n
   \end{align*}
   since $F_{X_{(n)}}(x) = F^n(x)$.
2. Note that, since $F(\theta) = 1$, we must have $X_{1}, \cdots, X_n \le \theta$ a.s., and therefore $X_{(n)} \le \theta$ a.s., and so we can just consider $(\theta - X_{(n)}) = |\theta - X_{(n)}|$ a.s.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now.